# AngularJS post form to external URL

Tags: angularjs

I have the following form in my AngularJS app which contain hidden fields with values filled based on user selection on some inputs on the form (radio buttons...etc), when the user click on the Submit link I should route the user to an external URL while passing hidden fields just as any normal form submission. Unfortunately I can't do this as some of the hidden field values are dependent on some calculations inside a function of the view related controller (as shown below in controller code, so I was wondering is there a way I can call the controller function from this form, then the controller function post the whole form and its field? Any example is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Note I am using  link instead of a button.

```
   <form name="clientPaymentForm" id="clientPaymentForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <input id="name" type="text" required placeholder="Client Name" ng-model="client.name">
          ...
          ...
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" ng-value="order.total">
          ...
          ...
          <a class="orderButton" href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('clientPaymentForm').submit(); return false;">Order Now</a>
        </fieldset>              

      </div>

     </form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.processOrder = function(){
  //Order calculation happens here to update order.total value and can only happen after click click Order Now to place the order...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit late, but what you want to use is the ng-click directive which will allow you to call functions defined directly on the scope.

Assuming that you've defined $scope.processOrder, change your a tag to the following:

```
<a class="orderButton" ng-click="processOrder()">Order Now</a>
```

And everything should work as hoped.

Alternatively, you could use ng-submit on the form to have it work when you press the "Enter" or "Return" key, as in:

```
<form name="clientPaymentForm" id="clientPaymentForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" ng-click="processOrder()">.
```